# h2 database integrated in spring does not save files after stopping executing ,

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2

i want to use h2 database using spring boot , but after every launching the code my database start from 0 , it doesnt not save files what i added before .Is it actually possible that if i stop my server running the database is saved or it is not ,because then i have second   question , what happened  if my server is stopped by accident all my records gonna be deleted ?

my app properties file ;

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your data source url as following

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:testdb
```

You have to put `file` keyword rather than `mem`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/<dbName>
```

Answer (score 0):

h2 is an in-memory database.when you restart the server all the data will be deleted.